# Translating into single line having the qualification name, subjects and its grades

Tags: grammar, translation

I've been trying to translate this single line of the qualification name, subjects, and its grades in Japanese and somehow it looks more challenging to me than how it's supposed to be. Here is the intended sentence in English.

```
CIE IGCSE Grade: A*A*AA in Physics, Biology, Chemistry and ICT.
```

My first attempt was to make it into this

```
CIE IGCSEの試験　物理学、生物学、化学と情報・コミュニケーション技術　A*A*AA判定
```

but I'm not quite sure because I didn't find the sentence pattern common to me, and these following attempts were more assuring to me (albeit a bit wordy),

```
CIE IGCSEの試験　物理学A*判定、生物学A*判定、化学A判定と情報・コミュニケーション技術A判定
```

or

```
CIE IGCSEの試験 判定

物理学: A*
生物学: A*
化学: A
情報・コミュニケーション技術: A
```

although I feel those Japanese sentences are natural when it'll be used to describe other scores that its English counterparts use number instead of alphabets e.g. IELTS scores because placing every number side by side in one line makes it look quite dense.

Thus, I'd like to know whether it's really possible to make a single Japanese line of it or not and whether the aforementioned single Japanese line looks fine or not.

Comment: I feel like this is more off-topic than on-.  It seems like the convention ultimately chosen has more to do with what is visually pleasing; not with a limitation of the language.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a one-liner, you can say:

> CIE IGCSE試験判定：物理学 A*、生物学 A*、化学 A、情報・コミュニケーション技術 A

Don't say "A, B, C**と**D" to list things like these in Japanese.

Even in English, I doubt people would readily interpret "A*A*AA" as referring to four separate exam grades. Is this a standard abbreviated notation that anyone familiar with IGCSE should understand? If not, let's write the exams and grades separately.